# JTextArea data appending not showing error but not displaying data when loading file

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, event-dispatch-thread

Here I'm Attaching the code snippet which should select the file and read that file by line and add that data to `JTextArea`.

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        File selectedFile;
        FileReader reader = null;
        BufferedReader in;
          String inputLine = "";
             double port1 = Math.random();
        long portNo = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
                System.out.println("portNo"+portNo);
            int LineNumber = 0;
        try {
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            DataInputStream inp=null;
            ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket((int) portNo);
                Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",(int) portNo);
                Socket socket1=ss.accept();
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            txtSearch.setText((fc.showOpenDialog(CreateNode.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) ? fc.getSelectedFile().toString() : txtSearch.getText());            
            if (fc.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                //gets file from dialog
                selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                //makes sure files can be processed before proceeding
                if (selectedFile.canRead() && selectedFile.exists()) {
                    //System.out.println("can read:"+selectedFile.canRead()+"exists:"+selectedFile.exists());
                    reader = new FileReader(selectedFile);
                }
            in = new BufferedReader(reader);

            //inputLine recieves file text


             DataOutputStream dos4=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while ((inputLine=in.readLine())!=null ) {
                //LineNumber isn't needed, but it adds a line count on the left, nice
               // inputLine=in.readLine();
               System.out.println("inputline"+inputLine+"LineNumber:"+LineNumber);
                LineNumber++;
                 fileData.append(LineNumber + ": " + inputLine + "\n");
                //next line in File opened
                dos4.writeUTF(LineNumber + ": " + inputLine + "\n");          
            }
               dos4.close();
             inp=new DataInputStream(socket1.getInputStream());

               String input = (String)inp.readUTF();
            //close stream, files stops loading
            in.close();
    }                                        
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception e:"+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here it's not showing any error and it's displaying the data in console(`sysout`) but it's not appending to text area.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: Thanks for comment but i'm new to swings(Jtextarea,jscrollpane etc..) and event-dispatch thread(i never heard about it) can you comment with more easiest and elaborated links

Comment: And please tidy up the code before posting:  1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Remove all the commented code lines.  In fact.. 4)  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: *"and elaborated links"*  'java edt swing' should lead to the goods, the moment you plug those magic terms into your favorite search engine.  But please don't expect people to spoon-feed information.  After all, I already provided a link in the first comment and you could not have had time to go through it properly, run the code samples etc..

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Thompson i'll try to know more about Swing edt

Comment: Also, do a search for SwingWorker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the code like followed

```
    File selectedFile;
        FileReader reader = null;
        BufferedReader in;
        try {
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            txtSearch.setText((fc.showOpenDialog(CreateNode.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) ? fc.getSelectedFile().toString() : txtSearch.getText());            
            if (fc.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                //gets file from dialog
                selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                //makes sure files can be processed before proceeding
                if (selectedFile.canRead() && selectedFile.exists()) {
                    //System.out.println("can read:"+selectedFile.canRead()+"exists:"+selectedFile.exists());
                    reader = new FileReader(selectedFile);

                }

            }
            in = new BufferedReader(reader);

            //inputLine recieves file text
            byte[] buffer;

            String inputLine = "";
             double port1 = Math.random();
        long portNo = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
                System.out.println("portNo"+portNo);
            int LineNumber = 0;
            while ((inputLine =in.readLine())!= null) {
                //LineNumber isn't needed, but it adds a line count on the left, nice
                LineNumber++;
               // StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inputLine);

                ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket((int) portNo);
                Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",(int) portNo);


                //displays text file
                fileData.append(LineNumber + ": " + inputLine + "\n");

             //   System.out.println("connected:"+socket.isConnected());

                 // ss.accept();
                DataOutputStream dos4=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                //next line in File opened
                dos4.writeUTF(LineNumber + ": " + inputLine + "\n");
                dos4.close();
                socket.close();

                Socket socket1=ss.accept();


               DataInputStream inp=new DataInputStream(socket1.getInputStream());
                //String msg=inp.readUTF();
                //System.out.println("msg:"+msg);


               String input = (String)inp.readUTF();
                System.out.println("inputline from socket:"+input);

                inp.close();

                ss.close();

            }
            //close stream, files stops loading
            in.close();

// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        
    catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Exception e:"+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: thanx @Logic Systems Java the whole thing is about looping i think

Answer (score 2):

no @mahender Reddy yasa it wasn't getting connect to the socket server just check out these steps are followed are not

1) start server

2) try to connect client with server